# The boundary morphisme of the cellular complexe of the n-Torus is the zero map.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I'm trying to compute the homology of the n-dimensional torus  $ T^{n} $ .
More specifically it cellular homology.

I'm tending to consider the following cellular structure of $ T^{n} $.

[image]

And as indicated in the statment, I'm trying to show that the degree of the composition [image]

is zero ; So that $ H_{p}(T^{n},\mathbb{Z}) = H_{p}( X^{(p-1)} / X^{(p-2)}) $ .

I think that it's sufficient to show that one piece of the composition above is non surjective.

My question is : how can i show that one of the applications is non surjective?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand all details as the notation is becomming a bit too technical at the end. However I understand to some extent the intuition behind this and this is too long for a comment. I hope you will be able to formalize this.

I think the map is surjective but has degree zero because of the equation "$1-1=0$". First you map $S^{p-1}$ realized as the boundary of a $p$-cube to the $p-1$ skeleton, which identifies all pairs of oposite faces. Then you factor out $p-2$-skeleton which converts it to a wedge of $p-1$ spheres: however, as your original boundary of the $p$-cube contains pairs of oposite faces, each such pair $P_1, P_2$ of opposite faces boils down to a map that maps $P_1$ to a copy of $S^{p-1}$ with degree 1 and maps $P_2$ to the same copy with degree $-1$.